# Перенос формулы mathtype в новый docx файл

Tags: python, xml, docx, python-docx

Использую библиотеку python-docx для форматирования статьи по гостам.
Возникла проблема с формулами формата MathType, не получается перенести их в новый отформатированный файл.
Пробовал использовать данный код:

```
    doc = Document(docx_file_path)
    redoc = Document(docx_file_path)
    p = redoc.add_paragraph()
    p_el=p._element

    elem = doc.paragraphs[0]._element
    for i in elem.getchildren():
        p_el.append(i)
```

К сожалению он либо не переносит формулы, либо переносит частично.
Но если вставить формулы в тот же файл, из которого они были взяты, то все формулы будут отображаться правильно, однако оригинальные формулы пропадут, оставив пустые строки, чье удаление через ворд ничего не сломает
Но если удалять в коде пустые параграфы, то формулы снова поедут.
Удалял я таким образом:

```
  doc.element.body.remove(doc.paragraphs[i]._element)
```